# cin vs scanf(), qual é mais rápido?

Tags: c, c++, desempenho, scanf, entrada-de-dados

Na programação competitiva é comum vários programadores usarem `scanf()` e `printf()` em código C++ ao invés de usarem `cin` e `cout`.

E inclusive já vi problemas que resultam em um *Time Limit Exceeded* (TLE - Tempo Limite Excedido) quando utilizados `cin` e `cout`, mas executam dentro do tempo quando usados `scanf()` e `printf()`, implementando a mesma ideia nos algoritmos.

Então fica a dúvida, `scanf()` é sempre mais rápido que `cin`, vai depender do caso ou `cin` é mais rápido?

Comment: [Referência](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-tutorial-basic-data-types) No site hackerrank ele comenta que para uma grande quantidade números é melhor usar scanf e printf. > You can also use cin and cout instead of scanf and printf; however, if you are taking a million numbers as input and printing a million lines, it is faster to use scanf and printf.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como a performance pode variar de acordo com a implementação, quem fará programação competitiva certamente testará isto na implementação usada para ter certeza de qual é melhor. Se a pessoa não souber que este é o caminho correto é melhor não entrar em competição.

Em um bom compilador (biblioteca padrão), sem *bugs*, bem escrito, se usar [`std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) e não fizer nenhuma maluquice, em tese é para ser basicamente a mesma performance. Dificilmente será igual, afinal são implementações diferentes.

Ao contrário da crença popular, tem uma chance razoável dos *streams* do C++ ser até um pouco mais rápido, pelo menos em alguns cenários (eu já vi [ganhos superiores a 25% para o `cin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12762166/221800)).

De qualquer forma há propostas para fazer uma nova maneira de formatação em C++ que aumenta muito a performance em todos os cenários.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Concordo plenamente contigo. Diria até que a implementação de um bom compilador *não precisa* ter preocupação excessiva com igualdade de desempenho, dado que o objetivo geral não é competição. Logo, talvez exista mesmo diferenças, mas são desconsideráveis para quase todos os cenários que não sejam o de competição. Mesmo assim, a minha intuição me diz que os streams do C++ tendem a ser mais lentos devido às indireções da implementação OO. Não acha? Se vc tiver alguma indicação do contrário, acho que seria bacana compartilhá-la na resposta. :)

Comment: Eu também achava, até ver alguns testes :) Vou ver se acho alguma. Eu acho que pode ser que o *overhead* do *parsing* da formatação pode ser a causa, mas estou chutando.

Comment: Verdade, pode ser.

Comment: cin good, scanf bad (não digo em termos de tempo, mas sim em termos de usabilidade)

Comment: @JoséX. também.