# Como fazer o Visual Studio não deixar usar funções sem incluir os cabeçalhos

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

No C++, o comando printf() e scanf() precisam da biblioteca cstdio para funcionar, mas no Visual Studio eu consigo rodar sem incluí-las. Como eu envio meus programas para um site que não permite isso, eu queria que o Visual Studio ficasse de olho nessas coisinhas e me avisasse que o `printf()`, por exemplo, não está incluído.

Comment: Fora o fato de usar `printf()` em C++, ainda mais no 14 ser algo altamente indesejável, não para saber qual é a dúvida na forma exposta. Poderia melhorar isso pra gente poder ajudar. Detalhe mais o problema, coloque o que está acontecendo em que situação. Tem partes do texto que sequer fazem sentido.

Comment: Eu gosto de resolver questões no URI e lá tem um rank de eficiência(tempo 0.000) sempre as questões com printf e scanf tem mais eficiência. Eu percebi que quando eu incluo o iostream, é como se o scanf e o printf estivessem dentro do iostream, eu queria que ele desconsiderasse isso.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126240/101

Comment: Isso provavelmente aparece no log de alertas do compilador. Procure por coisas como "declaração implícita na linha...".

Comment: Opa! Eu tenho uma print aqui mostrando a diferença que fez em tempo de execução em uma questão do URI Online Judge: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/sem_titulo-png--16717